# Отправка HTML-письма с изображениями с помощью email.mime python

Tags: python, html, email, smtplib, mime

**Дано:** HTML - файл с привязанными к нему картинками, которые лежат в той же директории.

**Надо:** отправить письмо так, чтобы оно отображалось у получателя как HTML-страница с картинками на своём месте.

**Что я пытался делать:** У меня есть код python, который отправляет HTML, но у получателя вместо картинок просто прямоугольники с красными крестиками (нет картинок).

**Вот мой код:**

```py
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.header import Header


def mail_sender(recip, subj, text):
    DEFAULT_SMTP_SERVER = '.................'

    SENDER = '...................'
    RECIPIENT = recip
    RECIPIENT2 = '........................'

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['From'] = SENDER
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
    msg['Bcc'] = RECIPIENT2
    sub_hed = subj
    msg['Subject'] = Header(sub_hed, 'utf-8').encode()
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'html'))

    message = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP(DEFAULT_SMTP_SERVER)
    server.sendmail(SENDER, [RECIPIENT], message)
    server.sendmail(SENDER, [RECIPIENT2], message)
    server.quit()


f = open('TestHTML.html', 'r')
result = f.read()
mail_sender('example@mail.ru', 'тест', result)
```

**ВОПРОС:** Как сделать так, чтобы получатель видел полноценный HTML-шаблон с картинками? Может быть, подход неправильный или что-то надо изменить в коде?

Comment: Ну так отправляйте картинки и всё остальное. Предварительно упаковав это в zip или rar архив.

Comment: И как картинки попадут из архива на поле письма в нужное место?

Comment: Картинки это статика, вы их отправляете? Ваша цель конечная не ясна.

Comment: Каким образом ваш получатель открывает html? "чтобы оно отображалось у получателя как HTML-страница с картинками на своём месте" где отображалась? Можно открыть в браузере можно в HEX-редакторе вы уж определитесь а потом оставляйте дебильные коменты "И как картинки попадут из архива на поле письма в нужное место?"

Comment: Есть папка с html и статикой, эту папку в архив, а архив отправьте пользователю он пусть извлечёт, а потом откроет в своём браузере.

Comment: Получатель открывает письмо в outlook express. На поле письма должен отображаться HTML-документ со всей статикой без всяких скачиваний приложений и разархивирования архивов.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое outlook express, но что-бы html отобразил картинку она должна быть рядом с ним.

Comment: Очевидно же, Капитан))) Не поверите, но такие письма есть и они работают. В этом и суть вопроса: как увязать статику с HTML избегая обычного вложения.

Comment: Переведи тогда картинку в base64 и зашей в html.

Comment: Типа так <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4RiDRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..." width="100" height="50" alt="base64 test">, если проблема только в картинках. По идее вопрос в другом у вас а именно как запихать статику в html. А остальное у вас не относится к теме вопроса. Переведите картинки в base64 и прям текстом копипаста в html.

Comment: Это интересно. Вот с этого места поподробнее...Можно пример кода? короткий.

Comment: Если не получится напишите.

Answer (score 0):

Решено синтезом строки base64 из картинки:

```
import base64

with open('images/image009.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    binary_fc = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    base64_utf8_str = base64.b64encode(binary_fc).decode('utf-8')

ext = 'images/image009.jpg'.split('.')[-1]
dataurl = f'data:image/{ext};base64,{base64_utf8_str}'
print(dataurl)
```

С последующим вмонтированием в HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AA...../9k=" width="180" height="50" alt="base64 test">
```

Теперь картинка интегрирована в код монолитно.